# To convert a batch Labelme json files to a set of images and labels using anaconda prompt

Tags: python, image-processing, cmd

I have a dataset of image masks that were generated by the Labelme tool as JSON files and on the Github tutorial (https://github.com/wkentaro/labelme/tree/master/examples/tutorial) it shows to change the JSON file into an image file we use the following command line code

```
labelme_json_to_dataset apc2016_obj3.json -o apc2016_obj3_json
```

however this only works for one file at a time, so I have been trying to find a way to process all the files using one set of code, I've tried the following code

```
setlocal
set "yourDir=C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\datasets\combined masks\"
set "yourExt=*.json"
pushd %yourDir%
for %%a in (*%yourExt%)do labelme_json_to_dataset %%a -o %%a
popd
endlocal
```

the code works now by reading the name of the file and adding the file extension .json however, saving the file to a directory with the same name including the .json extension is giving me the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\acer\.conda\envs\labelme\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\acer\.conda\envs\labelme\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\ACER\.conda\envs\labelme\Scripts\labelme_json_to_dataset.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "c:\users\acer\.conda\envs\labelme\lib\site-packages\labelme\cli\json_to_dataset.py", line 65, in main
    PIL.Image.fromarray(img).save(osp.join(out_dir, 'img.png'))
  File "c:\users\acer\.conda\envs\labelme\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2131, in save
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "w+b")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '000828.json\\img.png'
```

I'm not familiar with cmd and require help saving the output to a directory with the file name without the .json extenstion

below is a single file example that shows how a successful run is supposed to look like
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tq9CS.jpg)

```
(labelme) C:\Users\ACER\Desktop\datasets\combined masks>labelme_json_to_dataset 000814.json -o 000814
[[1m[33mWARNING[0m] [36mjson_to_dataset[0m:[36mmain[0m:[36m15[0m - [1m[33mThis script is aimed to demonstrate how to convert the JSON file to a single image dataset.[0m
[[1m[33mWARNING[0m] [36mjson_to_dataset[0m:[36mmain[0m:[36m17[0m - [1m[33mIt won't handle multiple JSON files to generate a real-use dataset.[0m
[[1m[37mINFO   [0m] [36mjson_to_dataset[0m:[36mmain[0m:[36m73[0m - [1m[37mSaved to: 000814[0m

(labelme) C:\Users\ACER\Desktop\datasets\combined masks>
```

Comment: In what way did the code "not work?" If there is an error message, please copy and paste it into the question as text. Please comment out or remove the `@echo off` in order to see what is happening. BTW, the code sets the variable `youDir` then uses a different variable `yourDir`.

Comment: thank you for that I had not noticed the mistakes

Comment: It looks like you are making progress. I do not know the `labelme_json_to_dataset ` program. It appears that you are specifying the same filename (%%a) for both input and output. What would a successful run of `labelme_json_to_dataset` using actual file names look like? Please paste it into the question as text.

Comment: I have made a lot of progress although I still do not know how to get the filename without the .json extension, I am going to upload an example of a successful run for a single file above to help illustrate how it is supposed to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the command `FOR /?` to read about `substitution of FOR variable references` on the last page of the help output. To get just the file basename, `%%~na` can be used. Run this without `ECHO OFF` so that you can see each command.

```
setlocal
set "yourDir=C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\datasets\combined masks\"
set "yourExt=*.json"
pushd %yourDir%
for %%a in (*%yourExt%) do (labelme_json_to_dataset %%a -o %%~na)
popd
endlocal
```

Comment: If this has been the solution, please select the check mark to indicate that it is the answer to the question. This will let others know it is the answer. This is how SO works.

Comment: This answer does not resolve the issue. `[WARNING] This script is aimed to demonstrate how to convert theJSON file to a single image dataset, and not to handlemultiple JSON files to generate a real-use dataset. (json_to_dataset.py:15)`

Answer (score 1):

```
import labelme
import os, sys
path="path/to/directory"
dirs = os.listdir(path)
i=0
for item in dirs:
   if item.endswith(".json"):
      if os.path.isfile(path+item):
         my_dest ="fin" + str(i)
         os.system("mkdir "+my_dest)
         os.system("labelme_json_to_dataset "+item+" -o "+my_dest)
         i=i+1
```

Comment: Could you put any context about how your solution would solve the issue? Please consider [answer]

Comment: [WARNING] This script is aimed to demonstrate how to convert theJSON file to a single image dataset, and not to handlemultiple JSON files to generate a real-use dataset. (json_to_dataset.py:15)

Comment: this code worked when tried in jupyter notebook

Answer (score 0):

```
for /l %n in (2,1,50) do 
    (labelme_json_to_dataset images%n.json -o images%n)
```

Every `file.json` and every blank folder (that's prepared before for saving dataset) are in the same folder (current dir for use this code).

Answer (score 0):

This solution is not perfect but just produces the mask and overlay png file. Also it just preserves the file name.

```
import argparse
import base64
import json
import os
import os.path as osp

import imgviz
import PIL.Image

from labelme.logger import logger
from labelme import utils


def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("json_file")
    parser.add_argument("-o", "--out", default=None)
    args = parser.parse_args()

    json_file = args.json_file

    if args.out is None:
        out_dir = osp.basename(json_file).replace(".", "_")
        out_dir = osp.join(osp.dirname(json_file), out_dir)
    else:
        out_dir = args.out
    if not osp.exists(out_dir):
        os.mkdir(out_dir)

    data = json.load(open(json_file))
    imageData = data.get("imageData")

    if not imageData:
        imagePath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(json_file), data["imagePath"])
        print(imagePath)
        with open(imagePath, "rb") as f:
            imageData = f.read()
            imageData = base64.b64encode(imageData).decode("utf-8")
    img = utils.img_b64_to_arr(imageData)
    label_name_to_value = {"_background_": 0}
    for shape in sorted(data["shapes"], key=lambda x: x["label"]):
        label_name = shape["label"]
        if label_name in label_name_to_value:
            label_value = label_name_to_value[label_name]
        else:
            label_value = len(label_name_to_value)
            label_name_to_value[label_name] = label_value
    lbl, _ = utils.labelme_shapes_to_label(img.shape, data["shapes"])

    label_names = [None] * (max(label_name_to_value.values()) + 1)
    for name, value in label_name_to_value.items():
        label_names[value] = name

    lbl_viz = imgviz.label2rgb(
        lbl, imgviz.asgray(img), label_names=label_names, loc="rb"
    )

    filename = str(json_file).split('.')[1]
    utils.lblsave(osp.join(out_dir, f'.{filename}.png'), lbl)
    PIL.Image.fromarray(lbl_viz).save(osp.join(out_dir, f'.{filename}_viz.png'))

    logger.info("Saved to: {}".format(out_dir))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```